# Como conectar android con MySQL externa

Tags: mysql, android, webservice

Soy nuevo en el mundo de programación android, actualmente trabajo en el código de una app en la cual quiero lograr que el formulario a llenar se envíe a la base de datos MySQL para ser verificada ¿Como podría lograr dicha conexión? Eh leído sobre un Web Service, pero no se si me convendría para este caso.
Tambien quiero lograr que al llenarse el formulario, en el momento se verifique si ya existe por ejemplo el mismo  nombre, email, etc(con su respectiva alerta de que no pueden usarse dichos datos ). Desde ya muchas gracias por su lectura.

Comment: Debes construir el backend para que sea consumida por la app android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los dispositivos móviles tienen pocos recursos, almacenar una base de datos en un dispositivo móvil acabaría con dichos recursos. Es por ello que en `android` de forma nativa solo existe una base de datos minimalista a la que te puedes conectar que es `SQLite`. Si te quieres conectar a otra base de datos (SQL Server, Oracle, Mysql, etc), la forma adecuada es crear un `WebService` que realice dicha conexión, administrada con la ayuda de un servidor de aplicaciones y el paso final es consumir dicho `WebService` desde tu aplicación `android`.